# Table floats to the wrong position no matter what I try

Tags: tables

I insert a table in the document using the following code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|ll}
\cline{1-3}
 $\textbf{N}$ &  $\textbf{Numerical Value}$  \\ \cline{1-3}
 1 & -0.252057   \\ \cline{1-3}
 3 & 0.0000319669   \\ \cline{1-3}
 7 & 2.22225*$10^{-16}$ \\ \cline{1-3}
 9 &  -7.852930072020838*$10^{-23}$  \\ \cline{1-3}
 17 &  -6.183886440905487*$10^{-52}$   \\ \cline{1-3}
 19&  8.334822280715465*$10^{-60}$  \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, it is placed in the wrong place, no matter if I place it under the relevant subsection. See the image before and after pasting the code in. How can I make it sit where it is supposed to sit?

Thanks!

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: table is a float environment, and so it floats. See here to understand how you can influence how it floats: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

Comment: side remark: don't use \\ to end a paragraph, this will only give you warning about underful boxes.

Comment: If you absolutely don't want your tables to float, you could just remove the table environment. If you do so, be warned that you might get some ugly half empty pages, especially if a table does not fit onto the page and is therefor pushed to the beginning of the next page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
```

and not

```
\begin{table}[]
```

That fixes it.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: If you like the answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: I am not allowed to vote, I have not enough reputation

Comment: @vqngs \*waves magic wand\* You do now!

Comment: Thanks for that!